# Changing metakeys in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Very quick question here guys.

I need to change the names of

- backdrop_path to field_backdrop
- release_date to field_date
- runtime to field_runtime

[image: database img here]

They are inside meta_key and inside wpto_postmeta

What code should i execute to change the name of those keys?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lookup the ALTER TABLE syntax for changing a column name

Comment: @SloanThrasher Re-read the question.

Comment: Are these just value in a column in two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very basic SQL.

```
UPDATE wpto_postmeta SET meta_key='field_backdrop' WHERE meta_key='backdrop_path'
```

(Repeat as needed for the others.)

Comment: If you're going to be poking around in phpMyAdmin, I **strongly** recommend taking a few basic SQL tutorials. It'll make life much easier.